# What is the proper way to make a link open in a new tab?

Tags: html

Is target=_blank the best way or is there something else that has replaced it?

Comment: Don't. The user can open a new tab if wanted

Answer (score 4):

This IMO is still the best way to do it. And will work with any sane browser even when everything else like javascript and the like fails. Even as I seem to recall that the target attribute at some time was removed from one or the other XHTML standard (I think XHTML Strict).

Answer (score 1):

It disappeared in XHTML Strict, but it would appear that `target="_blank"` [will remain in HTML5](http://html5.org/tools/web-apps-tracker?from=1470&to=1471), but browser makers will be encouraged to allow users to disable the behaviour (and default it to disabled).

Answer (score 0):

In [this article](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200605/using_javascript_instead_of_target_to_open_new_windows/) at [456 Berea Street](http://www.456bereastreet.com/), Roger Johansson recommends using JavaScript instead of the `_target` attribute, as the `_target` attribute is invalid in strict HTML/XHTML. However, he also recommends you avoid making links open in new windows as much as possible.

Comment: Right, use the option that could be disabled when target is consistently interpreted by browsers... Yet another reason using strict isn't a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

Remember HTML is only meant for content, not behaviour.  Hence we have CSS for layout and JS for behaviour.  For that reason you should use JS for the open in a new window functionality.  This is why XHTML strict doesn't allow target="_blank".